# Can I write 2D low-pass (fourier) filter as matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-transformations, fourier-transform

If I have a spatial domain signal **$f$** $ = f(n,m)$, n $\in$ $(0,\ldots,(N-1))$, m $\in$ $(0,\ldots,(M-1))$. Then **$F$**, the fourier transform of **$f$**, is defined as

$$F(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{NM}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1} f(n,m)\cdot \exp{\left(i2\pi\left(\frac{nx}{N} + \frac{my}{M}\right)\right)}$$

Considering I want a low-pass filter (call it a transformation $L$) that sets to $0$ elements of **$F$**, is it possible to define a matrix $T$, such as $f^*= Tf$? ($f^*$ being the filtered signal).

The whole filtering process is shown below, intuition says each every step can be written as matrix multiplication, but the proof seems complicated.

$$f \rightarrow^{FT} F \rightarrow^{L} F^* \rightarrow^{FT^{-1}} f^* $$

Comment: If your signal is put in a vector you can define an FFT as a sequence of matrix multiplications.

Comment: A convolution is usually a special type of matrix - Toeplitz or Circulant. If you increase the dimensionality you can still use Kronecker products to get around the increase in abstraction.

Comment: The $F^*$ will be a diagonal matrix multiplication if the filter is to be applied by convolution in the spatial domain.